# clean method for validation

Tags: django-forms

I have the following form class with corresponding clean methods...

```
class SOFIATMUserLogin(forms.Form):
Username=forms.CharField(label='Username')
Password=forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

def clean_Username(self):
user=self.cleaned_data['Username']
try:
SOFIALogin.objects.get(UserName=user)
except Exception:
raise forms.ValidationError('Username invalid...')

def clean_Password(self):
upass=self.cleaned_data['Password']
```

In the clean_Password method i wish to check if the password entered for the valid username is correct... So i need to get the Username value... How can i access this in clean_Password method... Please assist!!!!

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your question, you just need: self.cleaned_data['Username']